# Error whenever I try to add a string to a vector using find()

Tags: c++

So I'm coding and I am trying to add a string to a vector however whenever I would compile the function it returns

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ErrorException'
  what():  r���U
Aborted (core dumped)
```

but if I cout the string variable it works perfectly, how come it wont work when I try to push_back to the vector?

Here is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
  movie Data
    - returns data from the txt file and stores them in a vector
  Returns:
    - a vector with movie names and actors
*/
vector<string> movieData(string &filename)
{
  fstream myFile;
  vector<string> data;
  string content; //All the content casts and movie title
  myFile.open(filename);
  if(!myFile.good()) //If the file failed
  {
    cout << "File Not Found" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  while(getline(myFile, content, '\n')) //seperates each movie by the line
  {
    data.push_back(content);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  myFile.close();
  return data;
}
/*
  movie Title
    - a Vector with Movie Titles
  Returns:
    - a Vector only including the movie titles from each
      distinct line
*/
vector<string> movieTitle(vector<string> &data)
{
  vector<string> Titles;
  string word;
  for(int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++)
  {
    int pos = 0;
    pos = data[i].find("\t");
    Titles.push_back(data[i].substr(0, pos));
  }
  return Titles;
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> data; //contains titles and cast seperated by \t
                      //ex: Moon Knight (2022)\tOscar Issac\tEthan Hawke
  vector<string> Title;
  string filename = "movies_mpaa.txt";
  data = movieData(filename);
  Title = movieTitle(data);
  cout << "Title: "<< Title[Title.size()] << endl;
  cout << "Data: " << data[0] << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

I also ran it through the debugger and apparently the error or the thing that seems to be causing the problem is

`pos = data[i].find("\t"); //This iterates 2 times`

and

`Titles.push_back(data[i].substr(0, pos)); //This iterates 3 times`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because to me this logically makes sense.

Here is the [txt.file](https://easyupload.io/kq8wo7)

Comment: `Title.size()` is index one past the end of `Title`, so you can't use it like `Title[Title.size()]`

Comment: In case you want to access the last element of the vector, you can do `Title.back()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
  movie Data
    - returns data from the txt file and stores them in a vector
  Returns:
    - a vector with movie names and actors
*/
vector<string> movieData(string &filename)
{
  fstream myFile;
  vector<string> data;
  string content; //All the content casts and movie title
  myFile.open(filename);
  if(!myFile.good()) //If the file failed
  {
    cout << "File Not Found" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  while(getline(myFile, content, '\n')) //seperates each movie by the line
  {
    data.push_back(content);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  myFile.close();
  return data;
}
/*
  movie Title
    - a Vector with Movie Titles
  Returns:
    - a Vector only including the movie titles from each
      distinct line
*/
vector<string> movieTitle(vector<string> &data)
{
  vector<string> Titles;
  string word;
  for(int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++)
  {
    int pos = 0;
    pos = data[i].find("\t");
    Titles.push_back(data[i].substr(0, pos));
  }
  return Titles;
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> data; //contains titles and cast seperated by \t
                      //ex: Moon Knight (2022)\tOscar Issac\tEthan Hawke
  vector<string> Title;
  string filename = "movies_mpaa.txt";
  data = movieData(filename);
  Title = movieTitle(data);
  cout << "Title: "<< Title << endl;
  cout << "Data: " << data[0] << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

It was a syntax error in main();
`Title[Title.size()] change to --> Title`

Thank you @Yksisarvinen for the help